# Removing empty spaces from columns in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, parsing

I am trying to parse data in 2 columns, so that spaces no longer exist.    I found this piece of code which removes the trailing and leading spaces, but not the spaces contained within.  What changes should I make to this code, so that all spaces are removed

```
Sub Remove_Spaces()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("C:D")
rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng)

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306358/removing-all-spaces-in-string/42306558

Comment: Selection.Replace " ", "" will come in handy ;)

Comment: This worked for me and is super simple, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your requirement, is not based on VBA Code or by Macros.

It can be achieved in few steps : First of all I am giving below the Image Of the data I have used and results arrived at, for a ready reference.

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

[image: Step by Step Solution]

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I needed it to be automated.   Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: (1) Please do not post textual information as an image. (1a) We have a new capability for formatting tables; it should be used for spreadsheet data whenever possible. (1b) Purely textual information, like instructions, should always be posted as plain text. (2) Your answer depends on there being no more than four words per cell. At the very least, you should consider having Step 4 put the results into Column **E** and then put the `CONCATENATE` into Column D. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  But, even then, the `CONCATENATE` formula becomes cumbersome to type if some cell(s) have very many words. Can you at least improve on that aspect? (3) If you're going to give instructions, you should tell the user what to do. Step 6 seems to be saying that the user should type `H2 = CONCATENATE(…)` into Cell `H2`; of course that is wrong. Step 2 is similarly subject to misinterpretation. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (4) This strips leading zeroes, and trailing decimal zeroes (and decimal points), from numbers; for instance, try `Hello 0123 456.0 world`.  This ***might*** be acceptable to the OP, but it seems unlikely.  You should identify pitfalls like that and give warnings.  (5) Likewise, "words" that begin with `=` are a problem.  (6) You misspelled "Destination" in Step 4.

Comment: My Dear Scott, 1. I understand now that textual information should not be entered as image, henceforth I will never repeat that mistake. Thanks for drawing my attention . 2. In my answer for an illustration I have given 4 words. There is no limit on that. 3. The result is the parsing of Data as explained in Step 4, where is the question of Column E ?? If there were 10 words, then all next 10 Columns get populated with individual word. You have control only in selecting the destination; in our Case I said $D$2. It can be changed.

Comment: And what you say, CONCATENATE into column D ?? , is not understood by me.

Comment: I agree with you that for more number of words, CONCATENATE formula will become clumsy and inappropriate. (3) Here also I have understood your point. I am new in Answering. Next time I will write Enter the Formula in Cell H2 as.. (4) Yes Sir, Hello....world is not working as you said. If I know the pitfalls, then I must not have fallen like this !!! (5) Your suggestion is accepted, and shall be implemented. (6) I am good at Excel, not English. Because Editor is very good, it takes ample care so that I can only concentrate on the problem solving. THANKS A LOT. Keep advising.

Comment: When number of words are many, then how to improve upon. For trailing zeroes etc, what you have pointed is correct. if somebody wants, I will try to improve the solution. In my answer, Initially I pointed out that solution is not based on VBA or Macros. Because there were no reply coming forward, I thought of the solution. In giving answer only, we learn further.

Comment: Peter H has given a very good solution in One line, as against my so many words !!!.  HATS OFF.

Comment: Dear Scott, Just now I found solution of handing large number of words. To Concatenate large number of words ; Copy all words, then Paste Special TRANSPOSE in next column. ( Now Talking for one row, for MATRIX later.) Suppose my words are parsed up to column GZ, then Copy A1:GZ, paste it with SPECIAL PASTE TRANSPOSE, in cell HA. So you get all the words in Column HA. Enter formula in HB1 as =HA1. Now in HB2 enter formula =CONCATENATE(HB1,HA2), Copy this formula of HB2, down the Column HB,.....The last cell value give solution. Thanks for your advice, which makes me learn !!!

Comment: Sir, I correct my mistake where reference to cell was incorrect. Suppose my words are parsed up to Cell GZ1, then Copy A1:GZ1, paste it with SPECIAL PASTE TRANSPOSE, in cell HA1. So you get all the words in Column HA. Enter formula in HB1 as =HA1. Now in HB2 enter formula =CONCATENATE(HB1,HA2), Copy this formula of HB2, down the Column HB. The value of Last Cell of Column HB gives solution.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
Selection.Replace " ", ""
```

([suggested by PeterH](https://superuser.com/q/1642975/150988#comment2510794_1642975)) worked for me.